# Spring map properties stored in database table to map

Tags: java, spring

I have stored some properties in a database table so they are easily updated rather then having them in a property file. The table only has two columns (NAME, VALUE). I can retreive the `VALUE` from the database with the `NAME` using the following code

```
<bean id="otherPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="properties">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter" factory-method="getProperties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
                    <constructor-arg ref="pDataSource"/>
                     <constructor-arg value="dbo.APPLICATIONPROPERTIES"/>
                     <constructor-arg value="NAME"/>
                   <constructor-arg value="VALUE"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

so it can be passed to a string variable in a class like so

```
<bean id="generateUrlHelper" class="com.fexco.wuams.util.GenerateUrlHelper">
    <property name="url" value="${webPage.url}"/>
  </bean>
```

This sets my url variable to what is stored in the database. My question is, is there a way to return all the columns from the database table and populate a map so i can retrieve what ever VALUE i want from the map using the NAME?

E.G.

```
 <bean id="generateWuapsUrlHelper" class="com.fexco.wuams.util.GenerateWuapsUrlHelper">
        <property name="propertiesMap" value="fullApplicationPropertiesTable"/>
      </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else comes accross this issue, i could not resolve the issue the way i wanted by managed to do the following

```
<bean id="generateUrlHelper" class="com.fexco.wuams.util.GenerateUrlHelper">
    <property name="propertiesEditor" ref="systemPropertiesEditor"/>
    <property name="propertiesMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="driver" value="${driver}"/>
                <entry key="username" value="${username}"/>
                <entry key="password" value="${password}"/>
                ......
            </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

not the best solution as i am not dynamically retrieving the rows from the database but it will have to do for now